# File permissions conundrum

Tags: server, permissions, nginx, chmod

First, some background info about the server

> Running latest ubuntu and nginx. Nginx is set up for virtual hosts.
>   Users (100+ of them) are allowed to serve a website my placing
>   their html at $HOME/site.domain.com/public/ If their site is
>   security-sensitive, they can place a rsa key pair at
>   $HOME/site.domain.com.pem $HOME/site.domain.com.key and this gets
>   picked up by nginx and the html is served in https mode without
>   certificate errors.

The problem: What (chmod) permissions should $HOME/site.domain.com.key have?

Here are the constraints

```
- Other linux (non-root) users should not be able to "steal" .key files.
- Nginx runs as user www-data and group www-data I believe. So nginx needs to be able to have read access to any users .pem file when nginx is rebooted with `service nginx restart`
- Root users (root and ubuntu) should have access to any file using sudo
- To make user management easy, the users we added (not the ones that comes with ubuntu install) all have their primary group set as "ourcompanygroup". I'm flexible on this.
```

References: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: As long as the users are not part of the www-data group just make all the files in question owned by user:www-data and permissions 640 .

Comment: I forgot to mention that a) users don't have sudo chmod access b) I prefer not to get involved, I do have sudo chmod powers.

Comment: users do not need sudo powers to chown or chmod files they own (as long as they are in the www-data group)

Comment: i find this an interesting question. I'm not sure if this is the right place for consulting advice on setting up 100 client website though.

Comment: @WinEnuuchs2Unix it is easy to do with apache. See http://www.techytalk.info/enable-userdir-apache-module-ubuntu-debian-based-linux-distributions/ or similar. Works on other distros also. Then the second problem is the keys but again there are other options